# How can I generate an image in Ruby without external dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, maps, heatmap

I want to implement heat maps over Google maps with my own data beyond my Rails application. To do this I need to generate overlay images for each map coordinate (tile) based on my data.

I found how to generate that using ImageMagick but I do not want to depend on this, because I plan to distribute my application in several places, so I would like to do this using only the Ruby language.

Note that I need only to plot points in different colors over an small transparent square.

Comment: You'll also need to convert the raw image into a web format once you've generated it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think [chunky_png](https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png) or [oily_png](https://github.com/wvanbergen/oily_png) will be your best bet on this. It has no external dependencies on ImageMagick, and generates images in a web-usable format.

Comment: Note that Chunky is pure Ruby (and hence simpler and more portable) while Oily is a C extension that speeds certain operations up substantially, but requires that you are able to get the extension compiled on the target of your choice. I'd go with Chunky first and only go for Oily **if** Chunky turns out to be too slow.

Answer (score -2):

This is a big problem by itself, but is a resolved problem, see Geoserver or Mapserver.

- http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/rendering-transform.html
- http://mapserver.org/development/rfc/ms-rfc-108.html

Comment: Because links can stop working, we ask that answers not simply link to a solution. Could you edit your answer to include a summary of the solution(s) at the linked articles?

Comment: Nowadays Google implemented heatmaps layer, so it is possible to generate heatmaps without having to implement what this question was asking (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer), unless you are not using Google Maps. But thank you by the answer.