# Dynamically render a complex image in Rails with a template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add an action to my Rails app rendering a PNG image specific for a given user - some sort of a badge with user picture, name and some standard text. I want to embed the images in emails to be sent out to the users.

The whole badge is fairly complex image, so I am looking for an approach where I can reuse some sort of template image that I just need to update with a user picture and his name.

Would appreciate any examples or ideas on how to do it in rails (what gems can be helpful). Is it easy to have a Rails app to use SVG as a template and then convert it to PNG?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747029/how-can-i-generate-an-image-in-ruby-without-external-dependencies)

Basically, there are a few different gems you could use to create or manipulate images. Also check [ruby toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=image)